# Relationship between maximum and minimum of a function

Tags: optimization

Does $\max(f) = -\min(-f)$ hold generally?

Comment: Actually, it is $\max(f)=-\min(-f)$, provided at least one of them exists.

Comment: @sranthrop, the first minus sign does not exist.

Comment: If $f=3$, then $\max(f)=3$, $-f=-3$, $\min(-f)=-3$

Comment: sranthrop is correct. Will edit.

Doest it hold though?

Comment: @nomadStack: And now you know the answer. Dou you want to see a proof? :)

Comment: @sranthrop: Well, I'm not sure. I'm doing some optimization with my computer and I though, why not just use minimize algorithms like the Nelder-Mead on the product of the function with -1 instead of maximizing? I'm neither sure much this holds computationally, let alone mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that $\max(f)=m$. Then there exists some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=m$ and $f(x)\leq m$ for each $x$. This implies $-f(x)\geq -m$ and $-f(x_0)=-m$, so $\min(-f)=-m$.